# Conditional Banners

Tags: php, themes, javascript

I'm using banners/ads 
that are successfully displayed 
in every entry/post 
I created in my website.

¿Is there a way that banners 
can change to another banner
according to some field 
in the destiny post/entry?

Someone said "Yes". Thank you.

**How can that be done?**

I'm using the HTML clause DIV to put the banners. It does not admit conditionals as far as I know, so I guess I have to combine that with some code. Am I right?. The theme I'm using allow me to place some JavaScript code. **Can this JavaScript code reach the fields or information inside the destiny post/entry?**

So I can say something like this:

if entry.tag="banner1" then UsedBanner="Banner1.jpg"

and the DIV clause would receive the content of UsedBanner and display a banner that can be different for every entry/post.

**Where can I find specific information about this subject?**

Comment: Thank you for visiting WPSE. Please be sure to read the 'How to ask' section of our Help pages. As it stands the answer to your question is 'yes'. If you want a more specific answer you need to ask a more specific question, showing your code as it is now and which part you have a difficulty with.

Comment: Thank you. "Yes" is all what I needed for now. I'm going no modify  the question.

Comment: You could do different things depending on the value of a field, but what those things are would depend on how your banner/ad provider is implemented, you'd have to ask them for specifics on how to display different ads once you know how to differentiate between post meta values ( aka what ACF fields are saved as )